# Rails with Webpack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am using ReactOnRails app and I have `node-modules` folder with packages installed using `npm`. How can I make these javascript libaries available in `app/assets/javascript/application.js`, so I do not have to for example install `jquery` in my modules and in my `Gemfile`?

This is my webpack config file:

```
/* eslint comma-dangle: ["error",
  {"functions": "never", "arrays": "only-multiline", "objects":
"only-multiline"} ] */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const nodeEnv = devBuild ? 'development' : 'production';

const config = {
  entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/bundles/Home/startup/registration',
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-bundle.js',
    path: '../app/assets/webpack',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv),
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('react'),
        loader: 'imports?shim=es5-shim/es5-shim&sham=es5-shim/es5-sham',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;

if (devBuild) {
  console.log('Webpack dev build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  module.exports.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
} else {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
  );
  console.log('Webpack production build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using webpacker instead? https://github.com/rails/webpacker

Rails 5.1 will officially support webpack: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27288

Comment: I have not heard about webpacker yet. I will check it out.
And wow, that are some great news about rails 5.1!

Answer (score 7):

Rails 5.1 comes with [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) and removed default `jquery-rails` dependency, but you could still use it if you like. In template:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

will compile JS using traditional assets pipeline (from `app/assets/javascript/application.js`).

While

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
```

will compile your JS module from `app/javascript/packs/application.js` using webpacker. You can trigger manual module compilation using:

```
rails webpacker:compile
```

Comment: OMG thank you! `rails webpacker:compile` was what I was missing - I was wondering why my pack assets weren't updating!